# Validate order in Prestashop regarding database

Tags: database, prestashop

I'm currently wishing to validate my order in Prestashop.
In fact, for the need of a module, I don't use *validateOrder()* function from the file *PaymentModule.php*

By doing it manually, the order process is OK (with statut 'Payment accepted') but my order are not validated.

In database, which tables are filled in regarding the order process ? I would like to check my results in the database.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Your question should reflect the results of your research, and a specific programming related problem. By the way, your question could be easily answered by reading the code of Prestashop itself. Please add details to your question!

Answer (score 1):

When an order is placed in Prestashop, the data in entered in a few database tables.

1) **ps_orders** : Has the data regarding to the order like cart id, customer id, addresses ids, language in which order is placed, module which is used for payment and total order amount etc etc.

2) **ps_order_detail**: This table has all the products for a particular order.

3) **ps_order_history**: This table has the order statuses history. Whenever order status is changed, an entry is made here.

The above are the most commonly used tables. Please note that in particular prestashop versions, some additional tables may be used (new tables may be added to new versions), so you should check the data base tables started with order_  and so on.

You can verify it also by placing a normal order, and then by taking its id, you can check that what data is placed in what tables. Then in your module, you can enter the data for an order in that particular tables.
Hope this will help.

Thank you